# The package name and fingerprint pair you provided is already used by an Android OAuth 2.0 client ID in this project or another project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, sha1

I'm trying to create a new OAuth Client ID in Google cloud platform and I'm getting this message all the time but:

- I don't have this fingerprint used by this or another project
- The oauth list of IDs is empty

I only have that JSON translations API, apart from that it's empty, not sure what to change.

I have Firebase with Facebook/Gmail/Apple/email oauth for the login and I'd need this API for this: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12116/how-to-add-google-calendar-events-to-the-flutter-event-calendar-sfcalendar

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is already an android app using the same package name which you are trying to use.
You can try to validate the same by trying a different package once and see if you are able to complete your process without the error.

Comment: yeah, it works with a new name. I don't understand it then, the is the only place I have this app/package name

Comment: Somebody might have already used the package name you are trying to use.

Comment: that's quite improvable tbh. It has my name, lastname and app name. So what can I do now? I guess it won't work with a made up name right?

Comment: App name and package name can be different, I mean let say My App name is "Halo" and I was using package name as `dinkar.kumar.halo` and let's say this package was already taken so I can change it to something like `com.dinkar.kumar.halo` and then create a new fingerprint which this new package name and use that.

Comment: so I'd need to create another key and save that one with the one I have already and generate another fingerprint from it?

Comment: Yes, please so that everything is new and pointing to the correct package name(new package you are going to use)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231254/discussion-between-dinkar-kumar-and-dani).

Comment: But still pretty confusing that we need to do something like this. Google should provide more info about this and why we should have different package names with their fingerprints to avoid issues like this

Comment: One thing: the credential form says "From your AndroidManifest.xml file.". I can provide a new package name and create a new keystore providing with this a new SHA1 but I can't have a different package name in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: BTW, I do have Firebase with authentication as well. Not sure if the problem could come from this maybe?

Comment: Are you using different Google project for oauth and Firebase authentication for the same app?

Comment: No, that project in Google cloud is linked to the one I have in Firebase and in my app you can log in with Facebook/Gmail/Apple/email

Comment: If I am not mistaken login with all this can be directly handled by Firebase authentication from Firebase project, is there any reason you have one project in Google cloud and one in Firebase?

Comment: Correct, all of that it's in Firebase. I need this API in Google cloud for this: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12116/how-to-add-google-calendar-events-to-the-flutter-event-calendar-sfcalendar